# Behaviour difference in unloading table from redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to unload a big table from `Redshift` to `S3`. I tried the command twice with and without `GZIP` option. I noticed when the command is run without `GZIP`, it generates more and more files in S3 as time goes on. It generated about 150 files in two hours. I cancelled the query when I realised I didn't specify `GZIP`, then re-run the command with `GZIP` on. It hasn't generated any files after two hours.

```
UNLOAD ('select * from bigtable') to 's3://location/bigtable.csv'
CREDENTIALS 'cred' delimiter as ',' 
allowoverwrite addquotes escape parallel true gzip;
```

From storage perspective, I'd prefer to run with GZIP. However, this increases operational risk as if the query fails after 2 hours, I'll end up with no unloaded files at all.

I tried to see the difference in AWS's documentation but didn't see much useful information other than [`GZIP`compresses data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html).

Could anyone help me the fundamental reason behind this behaviour difference caused by GZIP?

Comment: how big is your table? this should work fine.

Comment: @JonScott, I know very well it should work. I'm asking if they're processed differently other than the compression part. The table is a few TB.

Comment: you should start to see the first .gz files quite soon after you start, i guess a couple of minutes max. It makes sense  to use .gz for this! Try it out on a subset first just to make sure all is OK (e.g. limit 100000.